# imagettftext и разный шрифт в одной строке

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток, в php очень большой новичок, но пытаюсь разбираться. Имеется такая задача.

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
$text4 = $_GET['text4'];
$text5 = ',00';
 
imagettftext($img, 100, 0, $x, 273, $color2, $font1, $text4 . ',' . $text5 );
```

Выводит картинку отлично, но мне необходимо что бы $text5 был другого размера и цвета. Как это можно решить?

Comment: добавить ещё один `imagettftext`, а из первого выкинуть вывод `$text5`. Неужели это так не очевидно?

Comment: Проблема в том что imagettftext сделан по центру картинки и $text4 может быть произвольной длинны, а $text5 должен быть сразу за $text4.

Comment: у функции `imagettftext` нет параметра "сделать по центру", а значит вы вычисляли нужную координату вручную. Значит и координату `$text5` вы с легкостью рассчитаете.

Comment: Вот таким образом я позиционирую `$text4`:

`$img_width = 1125;
$box = imagettfbbox(100, 0, $font1, $text4);
//вычисление ширины строки
$width = $box[2] - $box[0];
//вычисление коры x
$x = ($img_width - $width)/2;`

Ума не приложу как добавить в конце `$text5` и поместить обе переменные ровно по центру

Comment: У вас проблемы с математикой? Вы не можете вычислить боксы двух текстов, сложить ширину? Зная ширину первого блока не сможете вычислить начало координаты для второго блока? У вас проблемы не с программированием, а математикой первых классов. Печально